# Django 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to redirect a user upon completion of a form to another page without saving. However, when I use the reverse function, I'm getting an error: `'str' object has no attribute 'get'`

In the below class based view, the self.object.thing_id prints the data it should.

Class Based View:

```
class ThingUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        if self.object.status != 'initiated':
            print(self.object.thing_id)
            return reverse('thing:detail', kwargs={'thing_id': str(self.object.thing_id) })
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Even reverse('thing:list') gives the same error

App Things' urls.py

```
url(r'^$', ThingListView.as_view(), name='list'),
url(r'^(?P<thing_id>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/$', ThingDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^update/(?P<thing_id>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/$', ThingUpdateView.as_view(), name='update'),
```

This error occurs when the user hits the submit button on the html page. It kicks off the form and then is routed to the form_valid part. The self.objectstatus != 'initiated' and so it tries to do return the reverse.

This is the stack trace:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Starlord\Dev\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Starlord\Dev\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  142.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\Starlord\Dev\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  32.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /things/update/vd2dqvw3nw/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: You'd need a lot more details if you want help with this, for instance the line of code where the error occurs.

Comment: Any better? The stacktrace isn't very helpful. The error is called when the reverse is executed

Comment: `reverse()` returns a string.  `form_valid()` is supposed to return HTTP responses, not strings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use `HttpResponseRedirect` instead

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thing:detail', kwargs={'thing_id':self.object.thing_id}))
```

Comment: you are missing some parentheses, according to me, no?

Comment: @mrpepo877 Please note that this was answered 3 years ago. please let me know if I should update it.

Comment: acording to me should be like ```HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('thing:detail', kwargs={'thing_id':self.object.thing_id}))```

Comment: @mrpepo877 yes you are right, I missed some parentheses. Thank you